# matplotlib change vertical padding only between two specific columns of subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm creating a 2 by 3 array of plots with:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(
    nrows=2, ncols=3, figsize=(
        22, 10), gridspec_kw={
            'width_ratios': [
                0.7, 0.7, 1]})
```

I can adjust the vertical spacing with

```
plt.tight_layout(w_pad=5.0)
```

which adds a ton of space between each column in the array of plots.

But I want to put extra padding between column 2 and 3, and not between column 1 and 2. Is this possible?

Comment: Maybe you could add a narrow dummy column between columns 1 and 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would like to set multiple `wspace` values in `gridspec_kw` param when creating the subplots - which is not possible ([see here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.gridspec.GridSpec.html#matplotlib.gridspec.GridSpec)).

As far as I know, you have 2 solutions:

1. Create the axes using 2 `Gridspec`, one `Gridspec` per different `wspace`. (e.g see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24738578/control-wspace-for-matplotlib-subplots))
2. As [@JohanC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12046409/johanc) mentioned in the comments, create a useless "spacer" column. This is probably the easiest solution :

```py
fig, axs = plt.subplots(
    nrows=2, 
    ncols=4,  # add a new column ...
    figsize=(22, 10),                      
    # ... with a small ratio (3rd). This ratio controls the space.
    gridspec_kw={'width_ratios': [0.7, 0.7, 0.05, 1]}
)

for ax in axs[:, 2]: 
    ax.axis("off")  # Turn off axis lines and labels for this column
```

[image]